# Spring Boot multiple servlets error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two servlets in my Spring Boot application which are mapped via uri, 
one is mapped to /local/* to DispatcherServlet and another /* to VaadinServlet but when I try to just access something over /local/blabla the VaadinServlet is called too.

In my JBoss application this does not happen, is there any configuration I need to set in Spring Boot?

Another question I noticed why is there a mapping to '/'? Can I disable it, because I don't need to use this uri.

For Example:
https://localhost:9043/test/local/userRemote

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean vaadinServletRegistrationBean() {
    final ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new SpringVaadinServlet(),
            "/*");
    servletRegistrationBean.setOrder(10);
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
    final ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
    servletRegistrationBean.addUrlMappings("/local/*");
    servletRegistrationBean.setOrder(5);

    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
```

LOG

```
015-06-09 18:24:15.063  INFO 5344 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'portalPersistenceUnit'
2015-06-09 18:24:17.700  INFO 5344 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/local/*'], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@615c6a, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1060020, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6a5659, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@261998, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3b6765, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@a72925, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@62c887, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@fabf06, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@19a2203, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@ab398b]
2015-06-09 18:24:17.701  INFO 5344 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1c5d1f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@47637c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@18ab988, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@12afc39, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1df7359, org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter@2498a3, org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter@c2f767, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6f0f70, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@53ac0c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7ab205, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@c475ba, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@59c3ff, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@14f2020]
2015-06-09 18:24:17.763  INFO 5344 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/local/*]
2015-06-09 18:24:17.763  INFO 5344 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'springVaadinServlet' to [/*]
2015-06-09 18:24:17.763  INFO 5344 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-06-09 18:24:17.763  INFO 5344 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Servlet dispatcherServlet was not registered (possibly already registered?)
2015-06-09 18:24:17.763  INFO 5344 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-06-09 18:24:17.779  INFO 5344 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-06-09 18:24:17.779  INFO 5344 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'openEntityManagerInViewFilter' to: [/*]
2015-06-09 18:24:17.779  INFO 5344 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I could give details to DispatcherServlet via property file:

server.servlet-path=/local/*

Bu if want to disable DispatcherServlet, is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to override the default dispatcherServlet by creating a bean that has the same name as dispatcherServlet.  From a tutorial on the [leveluplunch website](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/011-add-servlet-mapping-to-dispatcherservlet-spring-boot/), I found the following:

```
@Bean
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    return new DispatcherServlet();
}

/**
 * Register dispatcherServlet programmatically 
 * 
 * @return ServletRegistrationBean
 */
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {

    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
        dispatcherServlet(), "/levelup/*");
    registration.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);

    return registration;
}
```